# Can keywords will be used as identifier in Python?

Tags: python

Can keywords be used as identifiers in Python?
Please explain about keywords and identifiers
can we use it in all workstation?

Yes or No
If yes then how?
If No then how?

Comment: No, you can't use keywords as identifiers.

Comment: _If No then how_ If the answer is no (which it is), then there is no "how".  It cannot be done.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty easy to find the answer to this question:

```
>>> class = 56
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    class = 56
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> def = 42
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    def = 42
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

No, you cannot use keywords as variable names.

However, you *can* use the names of built-in types as variable names. It shows up on SO all the time, and it's a very bad idea because that built-in type then becomes unavailable.

E.g.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> list = [42, 27]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: first argument must be callable or None
```

Comment: This isn't a complete answer; since Python 3.10, there are three "soft keywords" `match`, `case` and `_` which are permitted as identifiers in other contexts. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#soft-keywords